# .toLowerCase() not working among other things not working

Tags: javascript, html

JS

```
var score = 0

var yes = "yes"

var pokemonName = [];

var bg = [];

var index = 0;

document.getElementById('repete').style.visibility = 'hidden';


(function asyncLoop() {

  background = bg[num = Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')';
})();


function loop() {

  var myAnswer = document.getElementById("myAnswer");
  var answer = myAnswer.value;

  if (answer.toLowerCase().trim() == pokemonName[num].toLowerCase().trim()) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Correct, do you want to try again?";
    score++
    document.getElementById('repete').style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Incorrect, do you want to try again?" + "\n" + " The pokemon was " + pokemonName[num];
    document.getElementById('repete').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

function loopRepete() {

  var repete1 = document.getElementById("repete");
  var replay = repete1.value;

  if (replay.toLowerCase().trim() == yes.toLowerCase().trim()) {
    asyncLoop();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Goodbye, your score is " + score;
    location.href = 'index.html'
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Pokemon Quiz</title>

</head>

<body>


<lable> Answer </lable>
<input id="myAnswer" type="text">
<button onclick="loop()">click</button>
<p id="text"></p>

<div id="repete">
<lable> Answer </lable>
<input id="loop" type="text">
<button onclick="loopRepete()">click</button>
<p id="loopText"></p>
</div>
    <script src="Gen3.js">
    
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I try take the input from the second second button (div id = repete) and put a toLowerCase() on it it does not work, and we I remove the toLowerCase() it still doesn't work but doesn't show a console error on the page. So I am confused On what I need to try do. I have tried to google it, but I could not find anything that helped.

Comment: yes has been defined at the very top, and where did i use just 'pokemon'?

Comment: You're trying to take the `value` of a `div` in `var replay = repete1.value;`. They don't have values.

Comment: This fixed the problem thanks <3 
Now it is saying 
"asyncLoop is not defined" :D

Comment: That's because it's scoped to the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `num` exists in `pokemonName` array.
Otherwise, you'll be doing something like this:
`[1,2,3][5].toLowerCase()` which results in `undefined.toLowerCase()`, and you can't call `.toLowerCase()` on `undefined` as it only exists for `String`.

Comment: isnt num the what one in the array? num = Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)

Comment: First, `num` is based on `bg`, and you're trying to use it for `pokemonName`. Secondly, when both arrays are empty, `num` will be `0` and you'll try to get first element from empty array.

Comment: They have like ~150 items in them, i just removed them to make this smaller. Probably should of added that sorry.

Comment: yes, it's needed for reproduction, otherwise we can't debug

Comment: should I add them all back?

Comment: you should add code that when I run it - I'll get an error that you're getting. and specify what I should do to get the error, and which error exactly. you can use jsfiddle to create reproduction, or add snippet on here

Comment: I dont have a clue what you just said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238679/discussion-between-maxim-mazurok-and-sprat).

Answer (score 0):

If you want asyncLoop to be defined you can't wrap it in a IIFE like that.  I suspect you did that so it would run when the page loads, however there's another way to do that and still have the function defined for later use:

```
// define it like a normal function
function asyncLoop() {
  background = bg[num = Math.floor(Math.random() * bg.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + background + ')';
}
// and call it right away
asyncLoop();
```

Comment: Hi, this is an answer to your follow-up question.  If it helps - great.  However don't "accept" it because it doesn't directly answer the question above.

Comment: It does work, thanks, I have have a slight problem of the text not clearing, but I might be able to find an answer online thanks <3